# WPF inactivity and activity

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events

I'm trying to handle user inactivity and activity in a WPF application to fade some stuff in and out. After a lot of research, I decided to go with the (at least in my opinion) very elegant solution Hans Passant posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363117/shutdown-wpf-application-after-n-seconds-of-inactivity/2363364#2363364).

There's only one downside: As long as the cursor stays on top of the window, the [`PreProcessInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmanager.preprocessinput.aspx) event gets continously fired. I'm having a full-screen application, so this kills it. Any ideas how I can bypass this behaviour would be most appreciated.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly DispatcherTimer activityTimer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += Activity;

        activityTimer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            IsEnabled = true
        };
        activityTimer.Tick += Inactivity;
    }

    void Inactivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rectangle1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; // Update
        // Console.WriteLine("INACTIVE " + DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    }

    void Activity(object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
    {
        rectangle1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Update
        // Console.WriteLine("ACTIVE " + DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        activityTimer.Stop();
        activityTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

**Update**

I could narrow down the described behaviour better (see the `rectangle1.Visibility` update in the above code). As long as the cursor rests on top of the window and for example the `Visibility` of a control is changed, the `PreProcessInput` is raised. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the `PreProcessInput` event and when it fires. MSDN wasn't very helpful here.

Comment: That code works great for me and `PreProcessInput` isn't raised when mouse is still over the `Window`. Do you get the same effect if you create a small app with just the code you posted? Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks! Indeed, it works with just the above code (shame on me). Anyhow, in my project I still have that strange behaviour. I'm researching and narrowing this down more and will provide more detailed information. For completeness, I'm using .NET 4.

Comment: @Meleak: I've updated the question so that the behaviour is actually comprehensible.

Comment: Try this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516505/c-sharp-wpf-inactivity-and-activity-application-idle-user-inactivity-auto-l

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I could figure out what caused the described behaviour.

For example when the `Visibility` of a control is changed, the [`PreProcessInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmanager.preprocessinput.aspx) event is raised with `PreProcessInputEventArgs.StagingItem.Input` of the type `InputReportEventArgs`.

The behaviour can be avoided by filtering the `InputEventArgs` for the types `MouseEventArgs` and `KeyboardEventArgs` in the `OnActivity` event and to verify if no mouse button is pressed and the position of the cursor is still the same as the application became inactive.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _activityTimer;
    private Point _inactiveMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += OnActivity;
        _activityTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), IsEnabled = true };
        _activityTimer.Tick += OnInactivity;
    }

    void OnInactivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // remember mouse position
        _inactiveMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(MainGrid);

        // set UI on inactivity
        rectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    void OnActivity(object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
    {
        InputEventArgs inputEventArgs = e.StagingItem.Input;

        if (inputEventArgs is MouseEventArgs || inputEventArgs is KeyboardEventArgs)
        {
            if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseEventArgs)
            {
                MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e.StagingItem.Input;

                // no button is pressed and the position is still the same as the application became inactive
                if (mouseEventArgs.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.XButton1 == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.XButton2 == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    _inactiveMousePosition == mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(MainGrid))
                    return;
            }

            // set UI on activity
            rectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            _activityTimer.Stop();
            _activityTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm using this from within a ViewModel and so don't have access to `MainGrid` (or form elements), is there another way of detecting the mouse move?

Comment: As a follow up to my comment above: I removed the whole `if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseMoveEventArgs)` statement, and it's working fine for me, detecting both clicks and mouse moves, while ignoring the mouse simply hovering over the application.

Answer (score 51):

We've had a similar need for our software... it's a WPF application as well, and as a security feature - a client can configure a time that their user's will be logged off if they are idle.

Below is the class that I made to wrap the Idle Detection code (which utilizes built in Windows functionality).

We simply have a timer tick ever 1 second to check if the idle time is greater than the specified threshold ... takes 0 CPU.

First, here's how to use the code:

```
var idleTime = IdleTimeDetector.GetIdleTimeInfo();

if (idleTime.IdleTime.TotalMinutes >= 5)
{
    // They are idle!
}
```

You can use this and also make sure that your WPF full screened app is "focused" to achieve your needs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BlahBlah
{
    public static class IdleTimeDetector
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        public static IdleTimeInfo GetIdleTimeInfo()
        {
            int systemUptime = Environment.TickCount,
                lastInputTicks = 0,
                idleTicks = 0;

            LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
            lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
            lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

            if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
            {
                lastInputTicks = (int)lastInputInfo.dwTime;

                idleTicks = systemUptime - lastInputTicks;
            }

            return new IdleTimeInfo
            {
                LastInputTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-1 * idleTicks),
                IdleTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, idleTicks),
                SystemUptimeMilliseconds = systemUptime,
            };
        }
    }

    public class IdleTimeInfo
    {
        public DateTime LastInputTime { get; internal set; }

        public TimeSpan IdleTime { get; internal set; }

        public int SystemUptimeMilliseconds { get; internal set; }
    }

    internal struct LASTINPUTINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: This little beauty saved me a decent amount of coding, thank you. Using windows built in functions is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: @Timothy, I am also showing an alert box after being idle for x time to inform user about auto log out. Is there any way I can reset the timer for that alert whenever user is not idle? As of now I need to reset the time for that alert on each activity of a user.

Comment: Your class works great. I use it like that: in windows_loaded I started the timer: DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start(); and in timer_tick I call this idle class and close the app after 15 min:  void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var idleTime = IdleTimeDetector.GetIdleTimeInfo();
            if (idleTime.IdleTime.TotalMinutes >= 15)
            {
                this.Close();
              
            }
           
        }

Comment: This solution will stop working after a certain amount of uptime (~50 days) due to 32-bit tick rollover. The pinvoke website, which this code is probably based on, says: `These samples do not take into account the rollover of the tick counter which will occur after ~50 days of uptime.` [This might be a potentially good workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55813501/1469494) this issue.

Comment: the class is checking the idle time across the system, not just the wpf application. Ideally I would like to close the app, if user lets say is on ms word for the last hour, therefore, wpf is not focused. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I implements the solution in a IdleDetector class. I have improved a little bit the code. The Iddle detector throw an IsIdle That can be intercepte ! It give that ! I wait for some comments.

```
public class IdleDetector
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _activityTimer;
    private Point _inactiveMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);

    private IInputElement _inputElement;
    private int _idleTime = 300;

    public event EventHandler IsIdle;

    public IdleDetector(IInputElement inputElement, int idleTime)
    {
        _inputElement = inputElement;
        InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += OnActivity;
        _activityTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(idleTime), IsEnabled = true };
        _activityTimer.Tick += OnInactivity;
    }

    public void ChangeIdleTime(int newIdleTime)
    {
        _idleTime = newIdleTime;

        _activityTimer.Stop();
        _activityTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newIdleTime);
        _activityTimer.Start();
    }

    void OnInactivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _inactiveMousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(_inputElement);
        _activityTimer.Stop();
        IsIdle?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    void OnActivity(object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
    {
        InputEventArgs inputEventArgs = e.StagingItem.Input;

        if (inputEventArgs is MouseEventArgs || inputEventArgs is KeyboardEventArgs)
        {
            if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseEventArgs)
            {
                MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e.StagingItem.Input;

                // no button is pressed and the position is still the same as the application became inactive
                if (mouseEventArgs.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.XButton1 == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    mouseEventArgs.XButton2 == MouseButtonState.Released &&
                    _inactiveMousePosition == mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(_inputElement))
                    return;
            }

            _activityTimer.Stop();
            _activityTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listening to `PreProcessInput` have you tried [PreviewMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousemove.aspx)?

Comment: I believe this is a better alternative. The only issue with it is that it's not directly accessible from a viewmodel like `PreProcessInput`. Instead you have to bind to it on the `MainWindow` of you app.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in Martin Buberl code, I found what I think is a cleaner way to handle the `PreProcessInput` event for user activity.

```
InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += InputManager_PreProcessInput;
```

I did it by checking the `e.StagingItem.Input` value for different mouse events and keyboard events:

```
private void InputManager_PreProcessInput(object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.StagingItem.Input)
    {
        //mouse button pressed
        case MouseButtonEventArgs mbea:
        //mouse wheel used
        case MouseWheelEventArgs mwea:
        //generic mouse event for `MouseMove` event
        case MouseEventArgs mea when (mea.RoutedEvent.Name.Equals(Mouse.MouseMoveEvent.Name)):
        //KeyBoard event
        case KeyEventArgs kea:
            //TODO: manage activity notification
            break;
    }
}
```

or, without the switch statement:

```
private void InputManager_PreProcessInput(object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseButtonEventArgs
        || e.StagingItem.Input is MouseWheelEventArgs
        || e.StagingItem.Input is KeyEventArgs
        || e.StagingItem.Input is MouseEventArgs mea && mea.RoutedEvent.Name.Equals(Mouse.MouseMoveEvent.Name)
        )
    {
        //TODO: manage activity notification
    }
}
```