# Idle Detection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, idle-timer

I'm new in using WPF so I have no Idea how to detect Idle time and show the main window after 5mins of Idle.

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to Maintain a timer for your WPF app .. Which get reset Whwnever any event occurs .. Thats how you can detect Idle time for your Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do;

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer (
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,// Or DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle
    (s, e) => { mainWindow.Activate(); }, // or something similar
    Application.Current.Dispatcher
);
```

picked up from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/811f5706-b9d7-414c-a590-cb9f6108b564/wpf-how-to-detect-application-idle)

Comment: How would the timer be reset when a user interacts with the application?

Comment: Good point. maybe recreate the timer as a result of Window.Activated event firing. Then when user brings to focus it resets. Or create the time and just stop and start it on Activated. Maybe use `InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput` and reset in the handler for this

Comment: A more complete implementation on the same principle is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4970019/2046117