# WPF how to effectively detect user activity

Tags: c#, wpf, events, android-activity

I have an application in which I have to logout after say x seconds of inactivity.
I therefore have a timer going on and calculating a timespan from the last user acitivity resetted with:

```
dtLastActivity = DateTime.Now;
```

So the problem is that I don't think it's the best approach to associate EVERY single event in my program with the afore mentioned code.
But in the end I don't need EVERY event: all what is useful is to track KEYPRESS and MOUSEUP.

**Would it be correct to track those two event in the MainWindow?**

I have to admit that I still have not put into practice this (but I will) for I am not sure that this is the best approach for the purpose in the title.

Being new to WPF I am also not clear **if tracking keyboard and mouse in the mainwindow shall not affect the behaviour in the children** (that are the controls that effectively are the target of the event).

Thank you in advance for any help.

---EDIT---
The proposed solutions are very elegant. Particularly this one:

```
    public static class IdleTimeDetector
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        public static IdleTimeInfo GetIdleTimeInfo()
        {
            int systemUptime = Environment.TickCount,
                    lastInputTicks = 0,
                    idleTicks = 0;

            LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
            lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
            lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

            if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
            {
                lastInputTicks = (int)lastInputInfo.dwTime;
                idleTicks = systemUptime - lastInputTicks;
            }

            return new IdleTimeInfo
            {
                LastInputTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-1 * idleTicks),
                IdleTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, idleTicks),
                SystemUptimeMilliseconds = systemUptime,
            };
        }
    }
```

but it is too automatic. I have no control over it.
E.g. if I use it from the beginning it gets idle BEFORE starting because my application has a quite long start time with splash screen, deserialization etc...

The solution proposed by Fruchtzwerg is much more similar to my needs because I get complete control over it. It has also the advantage that if I click on another application the timer is not resetted!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idle Detection in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286766/idle-detection-in-wpf); also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111615/getting-inactivity-idle-time-in-a-wpf-application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use the approach described by you. I running a timer and restart every interaction. The events of a window are:

```
PreviewMouseDown="Window_Action"
PreviewKeyDown="Window_Action"
```

Restarting the timer:

```
private void Window_Action(object Sender, InputEventArgs e)
{
  IdleTimer.Stop();
  IdleTimer.Start();
}
```

Never had any prolmems with this soultion. Restarting the timer takes under 80 ticks with a [stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So the resources are in my opinion no problem.

Also you can specify the userinteractions by adding terms in your event.

The Preview-Events are not disturbing other events. This tunneling-behavoiur is described [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/2397.aspx).

Comment: Your solution is just what I am searching for. I'd just like to know if you are confident that grabbing those events in the mainWindow doesn't affect children events in any way.